# Javascript new function without assigning it to a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a risk in declaring and calling a function without assigning it to a var ?

Normaly, I put my javascript this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function (ev) {

        var myFunc =  function () { 
            init();
    
            function init() {
                initEvents();
            };
    
            function initEvents() {
                ...
            };
    
        }();
```

But since the var is never used, and could conflict with another one in the global namespace, I am thinking of doing this instead:

```
  $(document).ready(function (ev) {

        new function () { 
            init();
    
            function init() {
                initEvents();
            };
    
            function initEvents() {
                ...
            };
    
        }();
```

Seems to work, but any danger ?

Based on the comments received, I think the solution would be to do this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function (ev) {
    
                init();
        
                function init() {
                    initEvents();
                };
        
                function initEvents() {
                    ...
                };
});
```

Comment: The `var` declared inside your "ready" handler won't cause problems with global variables; as you said, it isn't used anyway. Also, `new function()` is just as pointless as assigning to a variable you never use.

Comment: Anonymous functions are fine, don't need the new keyword. Although it looks like the function won't get called?

Comment: `Self-Invoking Anonymous Function` probably it what you need.

Comment: I removed the function declaration inside $(document).ready(), and looks like jquery is calling the function anyway.

Comment: The argument to `ready` is a function, which is what you're giving it; essentially every example of jQuery's `ready` is exactly this. It's unclear what the issue is/was.

Comment: I was trying to avoid declaring a local var to a function for nothing. Don't like useless code.

Comment: The indentation of your code (in the question) was slightly confusing as your closing `}()` was half-way between the doc ready and the inner function and the last one had it closer to the inner code than the outer doc.ready.   I've taken the liberty of lining these up, but left the missing `})` on doc ready on the first two as missing.

Comment: IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) (aka self-invoking anonymous function as named above) is useful if you want to wrap a variable, eg `(function($) { $(...); })(jQuery);` where $ is not defined as jquery outside the IIFE (eg via noconflict).   There's no point in having one as in your second example as it just runs the code that it would if it wasn't there (like your 3 "solution")

Comment: "*and could conflict with another one in the global namespace*" in the first code, `var myFunc` is not in the global namespace, it's scoped to the nearest function - the callback to doc.ready.  (noted above, but wanted to add why it won't cause problems)